# Django MySQL Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535

Tags: mysql

I am currently migrating my tables to a new MySQL database from SQLite. There were no issues when I migrate to SQLite but when I try to migrate on to MySQL, I get the error above.

I think it was due to my `textfields` taking up much of the space so I added a `max_length=500` attribute to all of them but the error persists.

This is the error:

[image]

Is there a way to resize the `textfield`, or resize the maximum row size? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no expanding the maximum. Look closer at the text fields and examine if they can be further reduced. The columns' character set can contribute a large factor to the space used. Could it also be the table isn't normalized?

Comment: The tables are not yet finalized. We add as we go so normalizing can come in the future, right? But I can try to add the column's character set as an option. Is there a charset that is optimized for minimizing the space used?

Comment: _"normalizing can come in the future, right?"_ -no. A normalised schema probably wouldn't have the problem you've got now. Kicking the issue down the road won't help.